# computing $\int_0^\epsilon e^xQ_2\left(\sqrt {ax},\sqrt{b-cx}\right)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, numerical-methods

I am trying to compute the following integral
$$\int_0^\epsilon e^xQ_2\left(\sqrt {ax},\sqrt{b-cx}\right)dx$$
where $\epsilon>0,a>0,b>0,b-c\epsilon>0$ and $Q_2$ is the Marcum $Q$ function.
I have searched the literature, it ensembles Nuttall $Q$ function. Any closed formulation or numerical solution will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use
$$Q_2\left(\sqrt {ax},\sqrt{b-cx}\right)=1-\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{ a^k }{2^k\,k! \,(k+1)!}\, x^k \,\gamma \left(k+2,\frac{b-c x}{2}\right)$$
$$\gamma \left(k+2,\frac{b-c x}{2}\right)=\Gamma (k+3)-\Gamma \left(k+3,\frac{1}{2} (b-c x)\right)$$ and expand the last term as a series around $x=0$.

Comment: I feel like I am doing circular math here. The problem is that $\epsilon$ may not be small in my case. I am wondering is it possible to get rid of this integral and write it as an exact solution in terms of a concise power series.